# How to use MvxResourceLoader.GetResourceStream in a Xamarin cross platform app

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I need to read in a database included as a resource (asset in Android) and write it back out to the location SQLite expects it to be at. In a Xamarin.Forms app this works in the Android project.

```
const string dataBaseName = "birdsnbflys.db3";
string dbPath = FileAccessHelper.GetLocalFilePath(dataBaseName);
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(dbPath))
{
    var dbAssetStream = Assets.Open(dataBaseName);
    var dbFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(dbPath, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    var buffer = new byte[1024];
    int b = buffer.Length;
    int length;
    while ((length = dbAssetStream.Read(buffer, 0, b)) > 0)
    {
        dbFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    dbFileStream.Flush();
    dbFileStream.Close();
    dbAssetStream.Close();
}
```

In an app using MvvmCross in need to do the same but haven't been able to find any examples or discussion of how to use the GetResourceStream method of the ResourceLoader plugin. I have an interface defined the Core PCL project and a platform specific implementation of that in the Android project. This is working to the point that I can use the ResourceExists method to determine if the specified file is actually there or not. Just don't know enough yet to be able to figure out how to use the GetResourceStream method.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Search for ResourceLoader at this link.  It has a couple examples linked to it.  https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins

Comment: As @PkL728 said try https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#resourceloader